# Excel How to make cell in tab 2 show the value of a cell in tab3 only if a certain value in dropdown cell from tab 1 is slected

Tags: excel

How Do I Make Sheet2 B3 show the value of Sheet3 A2 only If Sheet1 D4's drop down (containing: "Blue, Red, Yellow") has "Blue" selected?

Would this be a formula or VBA code?

Comment: I tried Formula: =IF(Sheet1!D4="Blue",Sheet2!B3,"", (Sheet1!D4="Yellow",Sheet2!B4,"", (Sheet1!D4="Red",Sheet2!B5,"")))

Answer (score 0):

Sheet3 B3

```
=IF(Sheet1!D4="Blue",Sheet2!B3,IF(Sheet1!D4="Yellow",Sheet2!B4,IF(Sheet1!D4="Red",Sheet2!B5,"")))
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B"&LOOKUP(Sheet1!D4,{"B","R","Y"},{3,4,5})),"")
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I add to it so each drop down (red and yellow) also has a condition?

Comment: I tried Formula: =IF(Sheet1!D4="Blue",Sheet2!B3,"", (Sheet1!D4="Yellow",Sheet2!B4,"", (Sheet1!D4="Red",Sheet2!B5,"")))